# How do I change People Search to show full names instead of login names?

Tags: search, forms-authentication, people-search

People Search is showing login names instead of full names

i.e. in case of showing John Doe it is showing johnd when searched

Is there a way to change it?

I am on FBA.

Comment: Am not an expert on this but i guess the people that might help need information about your membership provider and the changes to have made to the web.config.
Maybe you can cross check if people search works for a web app that uses classic authentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bet is the following:

when looking at the user profiles in your user profile application, your user profiles have a (mapped) "name" field that are either empty or contain the loginname. That name field is used to display the display username. When looking at the user profile property "name", you can see that it's internal name is "PreferredName"

When looking at the search application, you can check for the crawled properties. In the "People" category, you see that the crawled property "PreferredName" is mapped to People:PreferredName. This PreferredName is mapped to the metadata property "PreferredName", which is displayed in the search results.

The name field of the user profile application should be mapped the source that is containing your display names. This way, you don't have to make any changes to xslt or anything else.

Comment: That was complete answer!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check what's being returned as search results and if full name is being returned but not displayed, just modify the people search results web part's XSL to display correct field.

Check [Customize the People Search Results – Part 1](http://www.sharepointology.com/development/customize-the-people-search-results-part-1/)  and part 2 in same series.